# findInLine error only searches the first line

Tags: java

Here's the code:

```
BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\123.txt"));

Scanner scanner= new Scanner(in);
while((scanner.findInLine("abc"))!=null){
   if(scanner.hasNext()){
       System.out.println(scanner.next());
   }
}
```

findInLine only searches the first line not the others. So it prints nothing.
  How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be looping over *all* the lines - and then if the line matches, then print it out (or whatever). For example:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    // Now check the line, and do whatever you need.
}
```

Or you could still use `findInLine`, just explicitly calling `nextLine` as well:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    if (scanner.findInLine(...)) {
        ...
    }
    // Read to the end of the line whether we found something or not
    scanner.nextLine();
}
```